# How can I create a login page for a website that can both login with Fetch API on local host and login with Google Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, google-signin

**Problem:** there is a repetition between Login page and Home page

**Explanation**: Login with Google (of Firebase) will access the Home page, but the db.js (and conditions) of the machine will not receive the signal so it will return the Login page again.

**Wish**: can someone help me turn off this repetition. Here is the source code: (What I commented is the login part using Firebase)

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import './login.css'

// import { auth, provider } from './config'
// import { signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth";

function Login() {


const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
const [pass, setPass] = useState('');
const [incorrectPassword, setIncorrectPassword] = useState(false);
const usenavigate = useNavigate();

useEffect(() => {
    sessionStorage.clear();
}, []);

const ProceedLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.log('proceed');
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/user/" + username).then((res) => {
        return res.json();
    }).then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp)
        if (Object.keys(resp).length === 0) {
            alert('Please Enter valid user')
        } else {
            if (resp.pass === pass) {
                usenavigate('/');
                sessionStorage.setItem('username', username);
            } else {
                setIncorrectPassword(true);
            }
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        alert('login failed');
    });
}

// const [value, setValue] = useState('')
//     const handleClick = () => {
//         signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then((data) => {
//         setValue(data.user.email)
//         localStorage.setItem("email", data.user.email)
//     })
// }

// useEffect(() => {
//     setValue(localStorage.getItem('email'))
// }, []);


return (
    <div className="login-container">
        <div className="login-box">
            <h3>LOGIN</h3>
            <form onSubmit={ProceedLogin}>
                <div className="input-box">
                    <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                    <input required value={username} onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} placeholder="Username"></input>
                </div>
                <div className="input-box">
                    <label htmlFor="pass">Password</label>
                    <input required value={pass} onChange={(e) => { setPass(e.target.value); setIncorrectPassword(false); }}
                        type="password" placeholder="*********" autoComplete="current-password" style={{ borderColor: incorrectPassword ? 'red' : '' }} />
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Login</button>
            </form>
            <Link className="switch-btn" to={'/register'}>Don't have any account? <u>Register</u></Link>
            {/* <div>
                {value ? usenavigate('/') :
                    <button onClick={handleClick}>Login with Google</button>
                }
            </div> */}
        </div>
    </div>


)
}
export default Login;
```

can someone help me turn off this repetition.